# How to make a php file in bluehost that is reachable from ios app and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ios, remote-access, bluehost

I have already made my app so that it works on the ios simulator and a localhost server. Now I want to make my app so that it is reachable on ios devices. I have a website that is hosted by bluehost. If I could just write up the same php files that I wrote in the local server and it was reachable from the app and mysql, I think it would do the trick. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this. Is there a way to access my website's mysql from my ios app through php files (which are also on bluehost)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need one of the three (well you can make your own mode as well, but these are standard)

1. JSON
2. XML
3. CSV

Your php file on bluehost would be an URL which would open a stream and push information from the database and your IOS app needs to read it.

Comment: But how do I view my php file that is in bluehost through a url. I can only see the text of the file

Comment: You need to call a php file, the output (echo) of the php file would create a stream and deliver the file to your app directly you can use apache objects to achieve this